# rebuild index for APL table in Sybase

Tags: sap-ase

I use reorg rebuild index to maintain indexes on table with data lock, but what can I use with allpages locking table? how to maintain its indexes, then update statistics?

Answer (score 0):

For allpages, there’s jusr the classic method of dropping and recreating the clustered index.

Comment: Thank you RobV,  what about changing the lock scheme to data rows then rebuild indexes after that return the locking scheme to allpages